# Exists vs select count

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

In SQL Server, performance wise, it is better to use `IF EXISTS (select * ...)` than `IF (select count(1)...) > 0`...

However, it looks like Oracle does not allow `EXISTS` inside the `IF` statement, what would be an alternative to do that because using `IF select count(1) into...` is very inefficient performance wise?

Example of code:

```
IF (select count(1) from _TABLE where FIELD IS NULL) > 0 THEN
UPDATE TABLE _TABLE
SET FIELD = VAR    
WHERE FIELD IS NULL;
END IF;
```

Comment: Please show us the full PL/SQL code. It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That `if` is totally useless, because the `WHERE` clause does exactly the same thing. You are not optimizing anything here - it's actually the opposite: if there *are* rows where the column is NULL then you are running this test twice (because the `UPDATE` will *always* evaluate that condition)

Comment: Btw: if you think `count(1)` will be faster than `count(*)` you are mistaken as well.

Comment: I mean, it's just an example, sorry if I misled you here, the actualy query is very complex and I have to verify it returns rows before actually doing it. So, all in all,I have to run it twice and that slows it down a lot,.

Comment: I don't believe that you *have* to verify that it returns rows before running it. Are you aware that Oracle has a proper exception handling where you could deal with a "no rows found" situation?

Comment: yes, but what if my procedure has multiple select queries that could result in `no rows found`? How could I attach the exception block to this one query?

Comment: Put each query into a separate block with its own `exception` clause

Comment: Well I for one think it's nice that SQL Server has a performant way of doing work which is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Per:
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3069487275935

You could try:

```
  for x in ( select count(*) cnt
               from dual 
              where exists ( select NULL from foo where bar ) )
  loop
        if ( x.cnt = 1 ) 
        then
          found do something
        else 
          not found
        end if;
  end loop;
```

is one way (very fast, only runs the subquery as long as it "needs" to, where exists 
stops the subquery after hitting the first row)

That loop always executes at least once and at most once since a count(*) on a table 
without a group by clause ALWAYS returns at LEAST one row and at MOST one row (even of 
the table itself is empty!)

Answer (score 6):

the best way to write your code snippet is

```
UPDATE TABLE _TABLE
SET FIELD = VAR    
WHERE FIELD IS NULL;
```

i.e. just do the update. it will either process rows or not. if you needed to check if it did process rows then add afterwards

```
if (sql%rowcount > 0)
then
...
```

generally in cases where you have logic like

```
declare
  v_cnt number;
begin
select count(*) 
  into v_cnt 
  from TABLE 
 where ...;

if (v_cnt > 0) then..
```

its best to use ROWNUM = 1 because you DON'T CARE if there are 40 million rows..just have Oracle stop after finding 1 row.

```
declare
  v_cnt number;
begin
select count(*) 
  into v_cnt 
  from TABLE 
 where rownum = 1
   and ...;

if (v_cnt > 0) then..
```

or

```
select count(*) 
  into v_cnt 
  from dual
 where exists (select null 
                 from TABLE
                where ...);
```

whichever syntax you prefer.